# I'm attempting to put my logic in a separate file using module.exports and require, however, I can't seem to figure it out

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Recently I picked up Node.js + Express.js in order to pair them with Socket.io and make a real time chat application. The problem is that since I'm relatively inexperienced with Node.js and Express.js, I'm having some trouble figuring out where to put my logic and how to separate it in different files. Right now, the logic that creates my Socket.io namespaces is in the `www` file and I'm trying to figure out where to place it. Right now it looks like this:

`www` File:

```
var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);

let io = require('socket.io')(server);

servers.forEach((server) => {
    console.log(server.name)
    io.of(server.endpoint).on('connection',(socket) => {

        socket.on('messageToServer', (message) => {
            let roomName = Object.keys(socket.rooms)[1]
            let room = server.room.find((room) => {
                return room.name == roomName
            })
            room.history.push(message)

            io.of(server.endpoint).to(roomName).emit('messageToClient', message)
        })

        socket.on('joinRoom', (roomToJoin) => {

            let roomToLeave = Object.keys(socket.rooms)[1]

            socket.leave(roomToLeave)
            socket.join(roomToJoin)

            let room = server.room.find((room) => {
                return room.name == roomToJoin
            })

            socket.emit('chatHistory', room.history)
        })

    })
});
```

What I tried is the following - I created a `socket.js` file and put it in a folder called `utility`, moved the code from `www` to the `socket.js` file and tried exporting the server from my www file to my socket.js file so that Socket.io can access it:

`socket.js` File:

```
let server = require('../bin/www').server
let io = require('socket.io')(server);

function createSocketServers() {

    servers.forEach((server) => {
        console.log(server.name)
        io.of(server.endpoint).on('connection',(socket) => {

            socket.on('messageToServer', (message) => {
                let roomName = Object.keys(socket.rooms)[1]
                let room = server.room.find((room) => {
                    return room.name == roomName
                })
                room.history.push(message)

                io.of(server.endpoint).to(roomName).emit('messageToClient', message)
            })

            socket.on('joinRoom', (roomToJoin) => {

                let roomToLeave = Object.keys(socket.rooms)[1]

                socket.leave(roomToLeave)
                socket.join(roomToJoin)

                let room = server.room.find((room) => {
                    return room.name == roomToJoin
                })

                socket.emit('chatHistory', room.history)
            })

        })
    });
}

module.exports = createSocketServers
```

`www` File:

```
var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(app);
module.exports = server
require('../utility/socket').createSocketServers
```

As soon as I did that, my code stopped working, so I can only assume I haven't done it correctly, hence why I'm here asking for help. Thanks!

Comment: what's the error you see in the terminal??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine except this line

```
require('../utility/socket').createSocketServers
```

When you do, `module.exports = createSocketServers` in `socket.js` file, you actually exporting the constructor.

If you run what you require, it should work;

`require('../utility/socket')()`

If you want to keep it like you do now, you have to export an object from `socket.js` file;

`module.exports = { createSocketServers }`

After exporting your module like above, you have to run it like below;

`require('../utility/socket').createSocketServers()`

Comment: Thanks, it seems like this was the issue indeed.